# how do I fit a time-series multi head model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, conv-neural-network

I try to create a model by concatenating 2 models together.
The models I want to use, shall handle time series, and I'm experimenting with Conv1D layers.
As these have an 3D input shape batch_shape + (steps, input_dim) and the Keras TimeseriesGenerator is providing such, I'm happy being able to make use of it when handling single head models.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Input, Dense, Conv1D, BatchNormalization, 
                                     Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling1D,
                                     concatenate)
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model

data = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=300, freq='D'))
data['featureA'] = [random.random() for _ in range(len(data))]
data['featureB'] = [random.random() for _ in range(len(data))]
data['featureC'] = [random.random() for _ in range(len(data))]
data['featureD'] = [random.random() for _ in range(len(data))]
data['target']   = [random.random() for _ in range(len(data))]

Xtrain_AB, Xtest_AB, yTrain_AB, yTest_AB = train_test_split(data[['featureA', 'featureB']], 
                                                            data['target'], test_size=0.2,
                                                            shuffle=False)
Xtrain_CD, Xtest_CD, yTrain_CD, yTest_CD = train_test_split(data[['featureC', 'featureD']], 
                                                            data['target'], test_size=0.2,
                                                            shuffle=False)

n_steps = 5 

train_gen_AB = TimeseriesGenerator(Xtrain_AB, yTrain_AB,
                                length=n_steps, 
                                sampling_rate=1,
                                batch_size=64,
                                shuffle=False)
test_gen_AB = TimeseriesGenerator(Xtest_AB, yTest_AB,
                                length=n_steps, 
                                sampling_rate=1,
                                batch_size=64,
                                shuffle=False)

n_features_AB = len(Xtrain_AB.columns)
input_AB      = Input(shape=(n_steps, n_features_AB))
layer_AB      = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features_AB))(input_AB)
layer_AB      = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(layer_AB)
layer_AB      = Flatten()(layer_AB)
dense_AB      = Dense(50, activation='relu')(layer_AB)
output_AB     = Dense(1)(dense_AB)
model_AB      = Model(inputs=input_AB, outputs=output_AB)
model_AB.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model_AB.summary()
model_AB.fit(train_gen_AB, epochs=1, verbose=1)
print(f'evaluation: {model_AB.evaluate(test_gen_AB)}')

#plot_model(model_AB)

train_gen_CD = TimeseriesGenerator(Xtrain_CD, yTrain_CD,
                                length=n_steps, 
                                sampling_rate=1,
                                batch_size=64,
                                shuffle=False)
test_gen_CD = TimeseriesGenerator(Xtest_CD, yTest_CD,
                                length=n_steps, 
                                sampling_rate=1,
                                batch_size=64,
                                shuffle=False)

n_features_CD = len(Xtrain_CD.columns)
input_CD      = Input(shape=(n_steps, n_features_CD))
layer_CD      = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_steps, n_features_CD))(input_CD)
layer_CD      = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(layer_CD)
layer_CD      = Flatten()(layer_CD)
dense_CD      = Dense(50, activation='relu')(layer_CD)
output_CD     = Dense(1)(dense_CD)
model_CD      = Model(inputs=input_CD, outputs=output_CD)
model_CD.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model_CD.summary()
model_CD.fit(train_gen_CD, epochs=1, verbose=1)
print(f'evaluation: {model_CD.evaluate(test_gen_CD)}')

#plot_model(model_CD)
```

This works fine for each of the models:)

Now I would like to experiment with concatenating both models to one (as I think it might enable me later when adding additional 'heads' to train them in parallel, and I guess using such models might be easier as handling a lot of separated once) and get a dual-head model, which can easily be created like this

```
merge=concatenate(inputs=[layer_AB, layer_CD])
dense_merge     = Dense(50, activation='relu')(merge)
output_merge    = Dense(1)(dense_merge)
model_dual_head = Model(inputs=[input_AB, input_CD], outputs=output_merge)
model_dual_head.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model_dual_head.summary()
print(f'dual head model input_shape:{model_dual_head.input_shape}')
plot_model(model_dual_head)
```

This dual_head_model has an input_shape of 2 time 3D
`[(None, 5, 2), (None, 5, 2)]`
and looks finally this way
[image]

Unfortunately I don't know how to fit it :( and hope you will be able to provide me a solution on how to generate the needed shape of data.
I tried to provide the previously used generators as list
`model_dual_head.fit([train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD], epochs=1, verbose=1)`, and also lists of the raw input data frames `model_dual_head.fit(x=[Xtrain_AB, Xtrain_CD], y=[yTrain_AB, yTrain_CD], epochs=1, verbose=1)`, but it seems not to be in the right shape.

Thanks in advance

Wasili

---

based on Jacks comment
I tried the using following code

```
def doubleGen(gen1, gen2):
  assert(len(gen1) == len(gen2))
  for feature1, label1, feature2, label2 in (train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD):
    yield (feature1, feature2), label1 

gen = doubleGen(train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD)
model_dual_head.fit(gen, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

but unfortunatelly it does not work, as the input_shape is not the same

```
ValueError: Layer model_2 expects 2 input(s), but it received 4 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:2' shape=(None, None, None) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'ExpandDims_1:0' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

---

I adapted the parenthesis in the generator based on Jacks note and get a different error now.

```
def doubleGen(gen1, gen2):
  assert(len(gen1) == len(gen2))
  for (feature1, label1), (feature2, label2) in train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD:
    assert label1 == label2
    yield (feature1, feature2), label1 

gen = doubleGen(train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD)
model_dual_head.fit(gen, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

```
<ipython-input-8-e8971cd0f287> in doubleGen(gen1, gen2)
      1 def doubleGen(gen1, gen2):
      2   assert(len(gen1) == len(gen2))
----> 3   for (feature1, label1), (feature2, label2) in train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD:
      4     assert label1 == label2
      5     yield (feature1, feature2), label1

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I thought about using a plain index iterating the generators which does fix the shape topic, but this results in a NonType error

```
def doubleGen(gen1, gen2):
  assert(len(gen1) == len(gen2))
  for i in range(len(gen1)):
    feature1, label1 = gen1[i]
    feature2, label2 = gen2[i]
    #assert label1.all() == label2.all()
    yield (feature1, feature2), label1 

gen = doubleGen(train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD)
model_dual_head.fit(gen, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-6abda48a58c7> in <module>()
      8 
      9 gen = doubleGen(train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD)
---> 10 model_dual_head.fit(gen, epochs=1, verbose=1)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    853       # In this case we have created variables on the first call, so we run the
    854       # defunned version which is guaranteed to never create variables.
--> 855       return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
    856     elif self._stateful_fn is not None:
    857       # Release the lock early so that multiple threads can perform the call

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

---

The Notebook can be reached [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FIiQLzYpEBZwBvY4ASgUBUKkhaLvnxbR?usp=sharing)

---

Finally Jacks input helped to find the solution. There was just missing to zip both generators to be able to iterated through them :)

```
def doubleGen(gen1, gen2):
  assert(len(gen1) == len(gen2))
  for (feature1, label1), (feature2, label2) in zip(train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD):
    assert label1.all() == label2.all()
    yield (feature1, feature2), label1 

gen = doubleGen(train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD)
model_dual_head.fit(gen, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

```
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 14ms/step - loss: 0.1119
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f0dfd4de5d0>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if this already exists, but I believe you can create a new Generator that merges the two datasets. Assuming the two Generators are in lockstep, this should work:

```
for (input1, label1), (input2, label2) in generator1, generator2:
    assert label1 == label2
    yield (input1, input2), label1
```

This now gives a generator that yields both inputs as a tuple, and the common label as one data item. This could be a lambda, which would save the trouble of creating an entire Generator class.

Comment: thanks Jack, see my edited question. I haven't been able to get the right shape out of the new generator

Comment: The parentheses in the 'for' line are very important, they should match what the generators create. I have seen Generators that return tuples, and Generators that return lists of tuples (of the batch size). Generators might give (image, label) or [(image, label), ...] or ([image, ..], [label, ...]).

Comment: the generators need to be zipped
`for (feature1, label1), (feature2, label2) in zip(train_gen_AB, train_gen_CD):`